# Query path, php 5.2

Tags: php, php-5.2, querypath

Im using Querypath in my PHP. 
Since my linux is Debian Lenny that doesnt have support anymore, and I have no idea how to update it to debian Squeeze. I cant update its php, since it doesnt exist for Lenny (for what I read).

Using Querypath I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/company/httpdocs/2013/inc/qp.php on line 61

And this line is:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($klass) {
 $parts = explode('\\', $klass);
 if ($parts[0] == 'QueryPath') {
 $path = __DIR__ . '/' . implode('/', $parts) . '.php';
  if (file_exists($path)) {
    require $path;
  }
}
```

Do you know, hot I can convert it to "PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny13" ?

Comment: first of all, in your example, you are missing closing brackets in the end => });

Comment: Yes, I just copy paste to show what is in line 61. This is not my code. Its Querypath 3.0: http://querypath.org/  file (qp.php). I would like to change this file to make it work in 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.2 does not support anonymous functions.

Instead, try using a named function, represented by a string:

```
function my_function($kclass) {
    $parts = explode('\\', $klass);
    if ($parts[0] == 'QueryPath') {
        $path = __DIR__ . '/' . implode('/', $parts) . '.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require $path;
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('my_function');
```